# Page cycle ASP .NET User Control with Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a verry simple asp .net user control that has a submit button to hide a calendar server side control. Here is the code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs"     
    Inherits="WebApplication5.WebUserControl1" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[

    function Submit1_onclick() {
        alert("1");
        $('#<%=Calendar1.ClientID%>').hide();
        alert("2");
    }

// ]]>
</script>

<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return Submit1_onclick()" />
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
```

Now I include this user control in the default page of asp .net application. Here is the code for default page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"         AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5._Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CP" TagName="TitleBar" Src="WebUserControl1.ascx" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
       <CP:TitleBar runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

I can see the calendar control in the page and when I click on submit it does get hidden for a moment but then reappears. If I write all code in default.aspx it works perfectly. I know it has something to do with page life cycle but cannot figure out what? Please help!! Also what should be the correct way of writing this then...

Comment: [ASP.net page lifecycle overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submit refreshes the page, use button instead.

Change this:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return Submit1_onclick()" />
```

to this:

```
<input id="Submit1" type="button" value="submit" />

$(function(){
    $('#Submit1').click(function(){
        alert("1");
        $('#<%=Calendar1.ClientID%>').hide();
        alert("2");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine and it should work same as without usercontrol. The thing is that you dosen't require postback so write `return false;` after `alert("2");`

ie

```
   function Submit1_onclick() {
    alert("1");
    $('#<%=Calendar1.ClientID%>').hide();
    alert("2");
    return false;
}
```